# Update using user input for multiple arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

Hey everyone i've created a program that allows me to create,delete,update,list and retrieve user inputs for three arrays now i'm having an issue with my update function where i am unable to get the function to print the proper text instead of saying `Update Player: Player [player number] has a point total of [number of points] points`  it says`Update Player: Player System.int32[] has a point total of System.int32[] points`

does anyone know how to get this to work i'm thinking i need to store it into a new variable and just use the new variables for the update function but everytime i try it keep getting the same thing since the value between the new variable and old is the same and when the old one is changed the new one follows suit

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

namespace FinalArrays
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //The MAXPLAYERS constant is the physical table size
            const Int32 MAXPLAYERS = 23;

            //Declare the player tables
            Int32[] playerNumbers = new Int32[MAXPLAYERS];
            String[] playerLastNames = new String[MAXPLAYERS];
            Int32[] playerPoints = new Int32[MAXPLAYERS];

            //Keep track of the actual number of players (i.e. logical table size)
            Int32 playerCount = 0;

            //Main Driver
            char menuItem;
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the player system...\n");
            menuItem = GetMenuItem();
            while (menuItem != 'X')
            {
                ProcessMenuItem(menuItem, playerNumbers, playerLastNames, playerPoints, ref playerCount, MAXPLAYERS);
                menuItem = GetMenuItem();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nThank you, goodbye");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        //Returns either a 'C', 'R', 'U', 'D', 'L', or 'X' to the caller
        static char GetMenuItem()
        {
            char menuItem;
            DisplayMenu();
            menuItem = char.ToUpper(char.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
            while (menuItem != 'C' && menuItem != 'R' 
                && menuItem != 'L' && menuItem != 'X' && menuItem != 'U' && menuItem !='D')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nError - Invalid menu item");
                DisplayMenu();
                menuItem = char.ToUpper(char.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
            }
            return menuItem;
        }

        static void DisplayMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease pick an item:");
            Console.WriteLine("C - Create Player");
            Console.WriteLine("R - Retrieve Player");
            Console.WriteLine("U - Update Player");
            Console.WriteLine("D - Delete Player");
            Console.WriteLine("L - List Players");
            Console.WriteLine("X - Exit");
        }

        //Routes to the appropriate process routine based on the user menu choice
        static void ProcessMenuItem(Char menuItem, Int32[] playerNumbers, String[] playerLastNames,
            Int32[] playerPoints, ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
        {
            switch (menuItem)
            {
                case 'C':
                    ProcessCreate(playerNumbers, playerLastNames, playerPoints, ref playerCount, MAXPLAYERS);
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    ProcessList(playerNumbers, playerLastNames, playerPoints, playerCount);
                    break;
                case 'R': 
                    ProcessRetrieve(playerNumbers, playerLastNames, playerPoints, ref playerCount, MAXPLAYERS);
                    break;
                case 'U':
                    ProcessUpdate(playerNumbers,playerLastNames,playerPoints, playerCount,MAXPLAYERS);
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    ProcessDelete(playerNumbers, playerLastNames, playerPoints, playerCount, ref playerCount,MAXPLAYERS);
                    break;
            }
        }

        //Creates a player in the tables if the array is not already full and the name is not a duplicate
        static void ProcessCreate(Int32[] playerNumbers, String[] playerLastNames,
            Int32[] playerPoints, ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
        {
            Int32 number, points;
            String lastName;
            if (playerCount < MAXPLAYERS)
            {
                number = GetPositiveInteger("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's number");
                if (GetPlayerIndex(number, playerNumbers, playerCount) == -1)
                {
                    lastName = GetString("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's last name");
                    points = GetPositiveInteger("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's points");
                    InsertPlayer(number, lastName, points, playerNumbers, playerLastNames, playerPoints, ref playerCount);
                    Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: Number - {0}, Name - {1}, Points - {2}, created successfully", number, lastName, points);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: the player number already exists");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: the player roster is already full");

        }

        //Inserts the player at the correct location in the tables based on order of 
        //ascending player number. Unless the insert location is at the end, this 
        //requires shifting existing players down in order to make room 
        static void InsertPlayer(Int32 number, String lastName, Int32 points,
            Int32[] playerNumbers, String[] playerLastNames, Int32[] playerPoints,
            ref Int32 playerCount)
        {
            /* PUTS DATA IN NEXT AVALIABLE SLOT
            playerNumbers[playerCount] = number;
            playerLastNames[playerCount] = lastName;
            playerPoints[playerCount] = points;
            playerCount++;
            */

            // PUTS DATA IN PLAYER ASECENDING ORDER
            Int32 insertIndex, shiftCount;
            insertIndex = GetInsertIndex(number, playerNumbers, playerCount);
            for (shiftCount = playerCount; shiftCount > insertIndex; shiftCount--)
            {
                playerNumbers[shiftCount] = playerNumbers[shiftCount - 1];
                playerLastNames[shiftCount] = playerLastNames[shiftCount - 1];
                playerPoints[shiftCount] = playerPoints[shiftCount - 1];
            }
            playerNumbers[insertIndex] = number;
            playerLastNames[insertIndex] = lastName;
            playerPoints[insertIndex] = points;
            playerCount++;

        }
        //Returns the index of the first player number in the table that is greater
        //than the player number to be inserted
        static Int32 GetInsertIndex(Int32 playerNumber, Int32[] playerNumbers,
            Int32 playerCount)
        {
            Int32 index = 0;
            bool found = false;
            while (index < playerCount && found == false)
                if (playerNumbers[index] > playerNumber)
                    found = true;
                else
                    index++;
            return index;
        }

        //Returns the index of the player number in the table 
        //or -1 if the number is not found
        static Int32 GetPlayerIndex(Int32 playerNumber,
            Int32[] playerNumbers, Int32 playerCount)
        {
            Int32 index = 0;
            bool found = false;
            while (index < playerCount && found == false)
                if (playerNumbers[index] == playerNumber)
                    found = true;
                else
                    index++;
            if (found == false)
                index = -1;
            return index;
        }

        //Lists the players in the tables
        static void ProcessList(Int32[] playerNumbers, String[] playerLastNames,
            Int32[] playerPoints, Int32 playerCount)
        {

            if (playerCount > 0)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("\n{0,7}   {1,-25}{2,6}\n", "Number", "Last Name", "Points");
                for (Int32 player = 0; player < playerCount; player++)
                    if (playerLastNames[player].ToString().Length != 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0,7}   {1,-25}{2,6}", playerNumbers[player], playerLastNames[player], playerPoints[player]);
                    }
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nList Players: the roster is empty");
        }


        //Returns a positive integer
        static Int32 GetPositiveInteger(String prompt)
        {
            Int32 n;
            Console.WriteLine(prompt);
            n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            while (n < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nError: enter positive value");
                Console.WriteLine(prompt);
                n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            return n;
        }

        //Returns a non-empty string
        static String GetString(String prompt)
        {
            String returnString;
            Console.WriteLine(prompt);
            returnString = Console.ReadLine();
            while (returnString == "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nError: must enter keyboard data");
                Console.WriteLine(prompt);
                returnString = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            return returnString;
        }
        // retrieve single value from an array
        static void ProcessRetrieve(Int32[] playerNumbers, String[] playerLastNames,
            Int32[] playerPoints, ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
        {
            int player;// Player number to find
            int playerindex;//index of the player number in Array
            if (playerCount < MAXPLAYERS)
            {
                player = GetPositiveInteger("\nRetrieve Player: please enter the player's number"); 
                playerindex = GetPlayerIndex(player, playerNumbers, playerCount);
                if (playerindex != -1)
                {
                  //  if (playerLastNames[playerindex].ToString().Length!= 0)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("{0,7}{1,-25}{2,6}", playerNumbers[playerindex], playerLastNames[playerindex], playerPoints[playerindex]);
                        Console.WriteLine("\nRetrive Player: Number - {0}, Name - {1}, Points - {2}", playerNumbers[playerindex], playerLastNames[playerindex], playerPoints[playerindex]);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("\nRetrieve Player: player not found");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nRetrieve Player: the roster is empty");

        }
```

This is the Update function that i am having trouble with

```
static void ProcessUpdate(Int32[] playerNumbers,
    string[] playerLastnames, Int32[] playerpoints, Int32 playerCounts, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
    {
        int player;// Player number to find
        int playerindex;//index of the player number in Array

            int points;

            if (playerCounts < MAXPLAYERS || playerCounts == MAXPLAYERS)
            {
                player = GetPositiveInteger("\nUpdate Player: please enter the player's number");
                playerindex = GetPlayerIndex(player, playerNumbers, playerCounts);
                if (playerindex != -1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: Player {0} has a point total of {1} points",playerNumbers,playerpoints);
                    points = GetPositiveInteger("\nUpdate Player: please enter player's new point total");
                    Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: Number - {0}, Name - {1}, Points - {2}, successfully updated", playerNumbers[playerindex], playerLastnames[playerindex], playerpoints[playerindex]);



                    playerpoints[playerindex] = points;

                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: player not found");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: the roster is empty");
        }

            static void ProcessDelete(Int32[] playerNumbers, string[] playerLastnames, Int32[] playerpoints, Int32 playerCounts, ref Int32 playerCount,  Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
            {
                int player;// Player number to find
                int playerindex;//index of the player number in Array


                String lastName;
                int points;


                if (playerCounts < MAXPLAYERS || playerCounts == MAXPLAYERS)
                {
                    player = GetPositiveInteger("\nDelete Player: please enter the player's number");
                    playerindex = GetPlayerIndex(player, playerNumbers, playerCounts);

                    if (playerindex != -1)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("The player entry was sucessfully deleted");
                        Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: Number - {0}, Name - {1}, Points - {2}, deleted successfully", playerNumbers[playerindex], playerLastnames[playerindex], playerpoints[playerindex]);
                        lastName = "";
                        points = 0;
                        playerNumbers[playerindex] = 0;
                        playerLastnames[playerindex] = lastName;
                        playerpoints[playerindex] = points;
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: player not found");
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: the roster is empty");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You probably should only present the source that is relevant to the error, not the entire program.

Comment: I've seperated that from the rest to show where i am having issues so it would make assisting easier, i posted the entire program so to show my work and maybe there might be an issue somewhere else that might be causing the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not indexing the array.  Your WriteLine statement should be:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: Player {0} has a point total of {1} points",playerNumbers[playerIndex], playerpoints[playerIndex]);
```

Comment: thanks this one worked perfectly, i was over complicating things by wanting to declare and store the player to be updated into a separate variable when a simple method like this would work , thanks a lot I've been stumped on this for a while

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to print out the entire array. Change it to print out playerNumbers[playerindex] rather than just playerNumbers.

Answer (score 1):

i would store it in a list of player attributes rather than 3 separate arrays.  makes it a huge pain to deal with them the way you are doing it.

```
class Player
{
    int number;
    int score;
    string lastName;
}
var players = new List<Player>();
```